# Unwrapping NSURL for NSData Constructor

Tags: ios, swift

I am hating Swift right now! What am I doing wrong? feed.media is a simple NSString not NSString?

[image]

Comment: Try `NSURL(string: feed.media)!`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to unwrap the url since the url methods return an optional. You're also missing part of the method name. You want one of these,

```
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: feedMedia)!)
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: feedMedia)!)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not an issue with `feed.media` but the fact that you are creating an NSURL inside of the method call and need to ensure the value will not be nil (since NSURL returns an optional) by unwrapping the NSURL with an `!`.